# Launching automaticly NodeJS when Electron builds

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I have been reading few posts about NodeJS/Electron and I am aware that Electron is a client side app.

However I would need to start a NodeJS server automaticly, without having to run "npm run start && node server.js".

For instance in the "main.ts" file, could I just run a spawn or an exec, such as

```
function launchAPI() {
  if(process.platform === "win32") {
    var cmd = 'npm.cmd';
  } else {
    var cmd = 'npm';
  }
  spawn(cmd , ['run', 'nodemon']);
}

try {

  launchAPI();
  // This method will be called when Electron has finished
  // initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
  // Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
  app.on('ready', createWindow);
}
```

In this way, by launching the built-in .exe file (which will be generated by Electron), it would also launch my API server. Otherwise, I would have to launch the .exe main Electron process and then open a command line and run node... Or eventually create a "launch.bat" which would launch Node et the Electron's .exe.

How could I start both of the processes (NodeJS API and the Electron app) only by starting Electron .exe file?

Hope I was clear there.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ideally, your node server should run independently. Your electron app request to that node server ( APIs)

Comment: @Mr.Ratnadeep so if I want to launch these two at the same time the best thing would be to build a .bat file who would start the Electron's .exe and the Node API?